# what is the Equivalent this code in c#

Tags: c#, php, c#-4.0

I dont know PHP and I am stucking at one Position can anybody help me.

I have a code in PHP.

```
    $binarySignature = hash_hmac('sha1', $stringToSign, $secretKey, true);

    // We need to base64-encode it and then url-encode that.
    $urlSafeSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($binarySignature));
```

Can anybody tell me what is the code in C# for above code.

Answer (score 0):

Taken mostly from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063004/what-is-the-net-equivalent-of-the-php-function-hash-hmac):

```
private string Hash(string message, byte[] secretKey)
{
   byte[] msgBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
   byte[] hashBytes;
   using (HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(secretKey))
   { 
       hashBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(msgBytes); 
   }
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++) 
         sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
   string hexString = sb.ToString();
   byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hexString);
   return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need something like this:

```
public string Encode(string input, byte [] key)
{
        HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( input );
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray ); 
        byte[] hashValue = myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream);
        return hashValue.ToString();
}
```

Also, checkout these threads:

[How to generate HMAC-SHA1 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067751/how-to-generate-hmac-sha1-in-c)

[HMAC SHA1 using the same value for key and message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934389/hmac-sha1-using-the-same-value-for-key-and-message)

Comment: I can't know exactly... but do checkout the above threads, unlike me, they actually explain everything. :)

Answer (score 0):

While calling

```
using (HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(secretKey,**true**))
   { 
       hashBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(msgBytes); 
   }
```

we need to pass true as a parameter.for me its working fine.